# print x over y in matplotlib python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to print x over y, but the `x/y` is not the ideal display. Is there a way to make it look like this one below? (put the horizontal dash/hypen between x and y). Thanks.

```
x
_
y
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the mathtext syntax like this:

```
plot.text(1, 1, r'$\frac{x}{y}$')
```

Comment: Many Thanks, it worked. But the font doesn't follow the settings for others (e.g. Times New Roman). Do I have to set sth separately for this? My current codes are like: `plt.xticks(ind,('SO$_\mathregular{x}$',r'$\frac{CO}{100}$',fontname='Times New Roman')`

Comment: That's tricky, look at https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/tutorials/text/mathtext.html#fonts

Comment: `r'$\mathregular{\frac{CO}{100}}$'` worked. Thanks for the inspiration.